# Gpxe Server hangs on loading ISO image

Tags: pxe-boot

My PXE Server (gpxe) is configured properly and I tested it a couple of times with different installations. However, sometimes it hangs while loading the ISO image which usually requires a reboot. A screen capture of the gpxe loading my ISO files would look like this:

```
Loading Memdisk
Loading http://192.168.x.x/images/redhat_linux_6.iso...............................
```

And it hangs. As I said a reboot usually fix the problem but I need to know why.

I am not sure where should I look or what I should change to have it load with no interruptions.

Now I cannot get the PXE server to load my ISO image, and it hangs consistently. I will `tcpdump` it and post it.

Comment: Anything useful in your web server's logs?

Comment: I will check my apache logs and update you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A memdisk approach usually needs RAM >= 1.3 x ISO image size at the client; could it be you are running out of memory?
2. A memdisk approach will fail as soon as the booted kernel enters in protected mode.
3. gpxe/ipxe are full of feature projects but also full of bugs and inconsistencies. Also gpxe hasn't been maintained in long time.

Today a safe PXE server when installing Linux initially boots kernel/initrd by TFTP transfers and next NFS/CIFS/HTTP shares transfer the rest of components on regular install distros or the big squashfs file in case of live distros.

Comment: I will try to do it with TFTP and will update you. Thank you.

Comment: You were right. TFTP is more reliable than HTTP, at least in my case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let me put it in a different way: a well designed standard PXE approach is not slower than a non-standard gpxe/ipxe based strategy and it is "much more" reliable. Bottom line when it comes to PXE attach to the standard.